# Pycharm ssh auto upload freeze

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm auto upload freezing when any connection error occurred.when freezed not able to close pycharm i have to close kill process in task manager or system reboot required .when i try close it showing this error message

> You have background tasks running. Are you sure you want to stop them
>   and exit PyCharm?

when i click exit I'm getting other message

> Automatic upload task is running. Proceed with project closing?

this is keep showing